# Máscara em imagem

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web

Estou tentando aplicar uma "máscara" em minha imagem, para pegar apenas o centro da mesma e aplicar `50px` por `52px`, tentei utilizar o `clip-path` mas não funciona, estou utilizando o **opera** e o **chrome** para testes, segue meu código:

**CSS**

```
.img_tamanho_icon
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 55px;
    clip-path: inset(52px 50px 52px 50px);
     -webkit-clip-path:inset(52px 50px 52px 50px);
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<img src="minhaImg.jpg" class="img_tamanho_icon">
```

Como eu poderia fazer isto? Sem perder a resolução da imagem, por exemplo "esticar" a mesma

Comment: Suporte da propriedade `clip-path`: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: Qual é o efeito desejado? Seria legal descrever melhor e postar uma imagem exemplificando, pois muitas vezes há ferramentas mais adequadas para se resolver o problema. Cuidado pra não cair no [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução é utilizar a imagem como plano de fundo de um elemento:

```css
.centro {
   width: 50px;
   height: 52px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center center;
   background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x100');
 }
```

```html
<div class="centro"></div>
```

Comment: o problema que ele acaba dando muito "zoom" na imagem, por ela ser muito maior do que estou delimitando.

Comment: Então você precisa redimensionar a imagem o mais próximo de 50x52? @MarcosHenrique

Comment: seria exatamente isso, ajudaria e muito, para ela não ficar esticada

Comment: Talvez a propriedade [background-size: cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) supra sua necessidade, atualizei o exemplo.. @MarcosHenrique

Comment: Com este exemplo consegui o que precisava, muito obrigado pela ajuda e atenção Lúcio.